# Mojave Hosts File

Tags: hosts

Was there some new behavior around the `/etc/hosts` file in Mojave? Cannot get the thing to pick up any new entries which I make in the file. I am restarting the DNS resolver thingy, and I vetted my hosts file for weird characters using `LC_ALL=C cat -vet /etc/hosts`. No luck.

Comment: Try making a change when the Mac is booted into Safe Mode and see if the change is retained after booting normally. It is possible that some (new) process is disallowing/rolling back your changes.

Comment: ^ ^ Or if that doesn't work, you could try single user mode.

Comment: Any chance you can show us a copy of your hosts file to make sure you're putting the entries in the correct format?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like this is due to my records being added in the wrong place in the hosts file. I needed to put my entries above the `255.255.255.255 broadcasthost` line. There's still some lingering issue about Chrome not using it, or maybe passing through to 8.8.8.8 for DNS if initial lookup fails. In Firefox my hosts file works as expected.

Comment: I can't get this to work. Mojave is ignoring host file entries. Why?

Comment: hard telling what the problem is, but the file I edited is at `/etc/hosts` not `/private/etc/hosts` and it was not working due to the order of entries.

Answer (score 1):

If you have mapping for multiple domains in single line that might not work.

```
1.2.3.4 example.com www.example.com
```

try splitting in to two lines

```
1.2.3.4 example.com
1.2.3.4 www.example.com
```

Thanks,

Comment: Thanks this was the problem for me because ddev was autowriting to my hosts file and appending them to a single line.

Answer (score 0):

- For OS X Mavericks and later, run this command to flush DNS cache:

  `sudo killall -HUP mDNSResponder`
- For OS X Mountain Lion and earlier, run this:

  `dscacheutil -flushcache; sudo killall -HUP mDNSResponder`

Answer (score -1):

Just another tip, even though it appears that the OP didn't do the following:

Hosts file changes in Mojave will not get implemented if /etc/hosts has been made a symbolic link to another hosts file, even with the correct syntax in it. It will fail to update with the sudo killall -HUP mDNSResponder command but then does not return an error code to let you know what has happened.

Don't make /etc/hosts a symlink in Mojave.